# df query on Timedelta column where duration <= 1 hour

Tags: python, pandas

```
#query that fetches all items where duration <= 1 hours
df = df[(df['Td'].dt.total_seconds() <= 3600) & (df['Td'].dt.total_seconds() >= 0)]
```

For example, the above query excludes items that start on `01/01/20 23:30:00` and end on `01/02/20 00:18:00`, however they need to be included!

If I add additional condition `(df['Td'].dt.total_seconds() >= -3600)` to the above query it starts including items such as `pd.Timedelta(days=-1, hours=23)`.

How can I make sure that the only items I fetch are within the duration of 1 hour  regardless of the day change that makes `pd.Timedelta(days=-1, hours=23)` evaluate to `hours=-1`?

**Example:**

`-3600 <= pd.Timedelta(days=-1, hours=23).total_seconds() <= 3600
True`

I don't want this included because 23 hours elapsed from the previous day not -3600 seconds/ -1 hours.

Comment: what are you comparing a series or rows?

Comment: what do you mean? I want to return all rows in my df WHERE timedeltas in `df['Td'] <= 1 hours`. I have values that go to another day as per my post.

Comment: can you add your sample input and output then please

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using unix timestamp. Deducted from given timedelta a timedelta object of the beginning of epoch and dividend the result by 60 to get minutes.